# Getting window ID of just-closed Chrome window using chrome.windows.OnRemoved

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple extension which pops up a window (for a radio player). I want to try and avoid having the extension popping up more than one radio player, so I want to...

1. set playing=false
2. If user clicks button, open a window ONLY IF playing=false
3. When opening window, set "playing=true" and get and store the pop-up window ID
4. Watch for closed windows, and if it's our pop-up window ID, then set "playing=false".

I'm getting stuck with step 4.

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(window) {
    alert (window.id);
});
```

...this returns "undefined" for the window.id - I'd rather it returned the windowId that has just been closed, so I can do something with it.

What is the obvious thing that I have missed?

**ANSWER**

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId) {
   alert(windowId);
});
```

...as it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.windows.onRemoved` returns `windowId`, not `window`:

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer windowId) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You helped me figure out the answer, though copying the stuff from the Google Extensions page isn't as helpful as it might have been.